# How to view a field in a table in an sql database and edit it using VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to write a program that will access a remote database and let the user edit different tables that are in the database.

My program currently connects to the database however I do not know how to select or display a particular table to the user.

Any help would be much appreciated. I do not know a lot of VB.NET so please be gentle with your answers

Answer (score 4):

If you are not familiar with `VB.NET` then your best bet would be to go through some tutorials either online or through a book.

- [MSDN Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388568)
- [Visual Basic .NET Programming for Beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/vbnet.html)
- [VB.NET Tutorial](http://vb.net-informations.com/)
- [VB.NET Tutorials](http://www.dotnetperls.com/vb)
- [How to Learn .NET and VB.NET online!](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/VB-NET-School)